# Why always null in form with field date? (in symfony2)

Tags: php, forms, date, symfony, datetime

I have a problem with Form in Symfony2,

This is mi form Code:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($pedido)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl("ec_main_guardar_pedido"))
            ->add('cliente','entity',array('class' =>'ECMainBundle:Clientes','property'=>'cliente'))
            ->add('fecha', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text',
                                         'format' => 'd-M-y',
                                         'required' => 'false',
                                         'read_only' => 'false'))
            ->add('fentrega', 'date',array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
            ->add('estado','hidden', array('data' => '3'))
            ->add('Guardar', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
```

The field 'fecha' don't work, i test with another formats, but i dont have solution, always say 'null', i try to generate the javascript to show one calendar, but the problem is the same, always null.

If in the Entity add this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->lineas = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->fecha= new \DateTime();
        $this->fentrega= new \DateTime();
    }
```

the field 'fecha' always is today.

And the field 'fentrega' with the widget choise work perfect.

Anyone can helpme please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the value attribute of `fecha` input equals `null` (`<input value="null" />`)?

Comment: When try persist the values, say this:      An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Pedidos (estado, fecha, fentrega, cliente_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["3", null, "2009-01-01", 3]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'fecha' cannot be null'

Comment: Is it NULL even if you pick a valid date? For example 20-8-2014?

Comment: As for the exception, you can avoid that by allowing null on that field: `* @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="datetime", nullable=true)`

Comment: Thanks, i see a mistake in the action to persist the data, and now when i type the date 20-8-2014 work perfect, but, when i use the calendar, whit this code:  `$('#form_fecha').datepicker({
   dateFormat : 'd-m-y',
   prevText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
   nextText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
   
  });` another time es null... any suggestion?

Comment: thanks bostaf, talking with you i find the problem... two days finding a solution... and thanks to you I have found.

Answer (score 1):

Well, now work perfect, the problem is the format of the date.

With this code work correct:

the controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($pedido)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl("ec_main_guardar_pedido"))
            ->add('cliente','entity',array('class' => 'ECMainBundle:Clientes','property'=>'cliente'))
            ->add('fecha', 'date', array('widget' => 'single_text',
                                         'format' => 'd-M-y'))
            ->add('fentrega', 'date',array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
            ->add('estado','hidden', array('data' => '3'))
            ->add('Guardar', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
```

in the view:

```
$('#form_fecha').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'd-m,-yy',
            prevText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            nextText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',

        });
```

the problem is `'format' => 'd-M-y')` is equal to `dateFormat : 'd-mm-yy'` the reason... i don't know...

Thanks all for the help

Comment: The reason is date format - it must be consistent between Symfony date Field Type and jQuery dateFormat option. They are different in both. In Symfony: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax, in jQuery: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate. So `d-M-y` in Symfony equals `d-mm-yy` in jQuery.

Comment: Oh, you need to edit your answer, it's not `dd-m-yy`. Symfony's `d-M-y` is `day-no-leading-zeros`-`month-with-leading-zeros`-`year-four-digits`, which datepicker format is `d-mm-yy`, as said in my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `__construct()` to set default data. After object is created (by __construct) Doctrine do its magic and override values set by a constructor.
Prepare method `setDefauts()` and put setting default data there. Then, after created model, ie. in controllers action run this method.

```
// /Acme/FooBundle/Entity/Bar.php
// ...
public function setDefaults()
{
    $this->fecha = new \DateTime();
    $this->fentrega = new \DateTime();
}
// ...


// /Acme/FooBundle/Controller/BarController.php
// ...
public function someAction()
{
    $var = new Bar();
    $var->setDefaults();
}
// ...
```